# Finding memory address of a kernel data structure

Tags: c, arrays, kernel, 32-bit, memory-address

There is an array in kernel called `zone_table` according to `page_alloc.c` it is an array of pointers pointing to zone_t (zone_struct) data structures:

```
/*
 *
 * The zone_table array is used to look up the address of the 
 * struct zone corresponding to a given zone number (ZONE_DMA,
 * ZONE_NORMAL, or ZONE_HIGHMEM).
 */
zone_t *zone_table[MAX_NR_ZONES*MAX_NR_NODES];
```

and I found its address from `System.map`

but as I guess this address `0xc04260c4` is address of `zone_table[0]`.

but I need address of `zone_table[1]`

I don't know how to calculate this address. I thought in a `32 bit x86` system maybe `0xc04260c4` should be added to `0x4` to access address of `zone_table[1]`. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array `zone_t * zone_table[]` then `zone_table[x]` is shorthand for `*(zone_table+x)`

**BUT** `+` in this case is pointer addition, so its `zone_table + sizeof(zone_t *) * x`

for `32 bit systems` `sizeof(zone_t *)` is indeed `4`

for `64 bit systems` `sizeof(zone_t *)` is `8`

Your assumption was correct:

if the address of `zone_table[0]` is `0xc04260c4`

then the address of `zone_table[1]` is `0xc04260c8`